# Hide Products from View in Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, drupal-modules

I know this may be very basic but I can't seem to figure out a way to hide a product that I've got set up in Drupal Commerce. I'm new to Drupal so thanks for your patience.

In the product's edit screen, I go to 'Status' and choose 'Disabled' which prevents them from being added to carts (instead of Add To Cart, it displays 'Product Not Available' in the store) but it doesn't actually remove it from Product Display in the store. I've set the stock status to 0 on these products and made sure that they are not being displayed as 'Featured' yet they still show up.

Is there a simple setting where I can keep the product in the backend, in case I want to activate it later, but hide it from the store?

Thanks so much for your help.

---

For clarification, I am using the 'Expressa' theme.

Comment: Unpublish the display content in this case.

Comment: Thanks @RajeevK, how do I unpublish a product type? I'm sorry, I've been Googling and poking around the site for a while now and can't seem to find where you can unpublish a certain product or product type.

Comment: If you navigate you your content list, you will find the list of content, where product display will also be there. You just check all those content(product display node) which you want to unpublish then by update option at top.

Comment: Hi @RajeevK, I've 'unpublished' all of those products and they are still showing...

Comment: @MxmastaMills if you are logged in to Drupal as an administrator, then you will still be able to see the page even if you have unpublished it.  Try viewing the page from a different browser or log out first and try viewing the unpublished content again to see if it's still visible

Comment: @nmc, unfortunately the products are still showing on a different browser when logged out.

Comment: @MxmastaMills Check the permission. If user type has permission to see unpublished content then only it will be visible for them.

Comment: @RajeevK, yeah that's what I was saying in that last comment. When I've viewed it in a different browser (not logged in), they are still showing?

Comment: @MxmastaMills I am asking you to check your permission list & see whether Anonymous user have permission to see unpublished content or not. They must have it, so change that..

Comment: Oh i see what you're saying. Well if I go on another browser and click on the product (in the product listing in the 'Store' tab of the site), it gives an error message saying that I am not authorized to access this content. It's not allowing me to see the actual page but it's still listing it in the store for some reason. Does that make sense?

Comment: @RajeevK, I checked permissions and anonymous users do not have permission to see unpublished content.

Comment: @MxmastaMills Yes. You have achieved what we were suggesting. Product is there in store but their display is not accessible by user.

Comment: @RajeevK, right but I don't want it viewed in the store at all (the preview/thumbnail and product listing are in the list of products which we are not looking for). Does that make sense? I'm not quite sure where to go from here...

Comment: @MxmastaMills Then just delete it. Until it is in system, it wil be in list :)

Comment: @MxmastaMills what is the path/url where your product is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I've worked with Drupal Commerce, but I assume that your product listing is a View.

You should be able to modify your View to filter out the disabled products.